# Godot export Android: Android resource linking failed, AAPT: error: unexpected element <queries> found in <manifest>

Tags: android, godot

I'm trying to export Godot project to Android apk, but I face this error:

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':processDebugResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > Android resource linking failed
     C:\Users\MyUsername\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\cc8b432f7a68a976550fb6c3054f84d5\play-services-ads-lite-20.5.0\AndroidManifest.xml:28:5-44:15: AAPT: error: unexpected element <queries> found in <manifest>.
```

I have tried to find it on internet but I found no solutions.
Does anyone have faced this issue before, pls help me out

Comment: I added ndkVersion "20.1.5948944" to android block in build.gradle file and it work fine, but I dont know why it not work with lastest NDK

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and after some research and debugging I finally found the solution. I solved the issue by upgrading `build.gradle` version.

Previous setting in `build.gradle` file of project was:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.1'
```

Current setting:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try and clean the project and clear the cache, then lastly invalidate the cache